# How to make image file accesible in Web API project?

Tags: c#

My Web API project creates a temporary image into folder named tmp and I need it accessible to everyone.. how to do this?

currently I got: HTTP ERROR 404

image files are created successfully, but I am unable to access it:

```
  https://example.com/demo/ior/api/tmp/AMRFHRNMUIMMSLO.jpeg
```

please help

thanks a lot in advance
Don

Comment: Is this an asp.net core api?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Web API"?  MVC 4/5?  .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is an asp.net core, You can simply create another endpoint which returns a FileStreamResult(a built in method into the controller class), you will have to provide the mime type though, which I assume is jpeg(These are the reasons why we ask you to provide proper context and if possible a minimal reproducible example). With that in mind Here's an example.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile()
{
    var temporaryImage = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Path to the file");
    //Replace "image/jpeg" with the mimetype of your image.
    return File(temporaryImage, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: I tried it.. but it still getting 404..

the controller name is "default"


       [HttpGet("{_filename}")]
              public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string _filename)
              {
                  var temporaryImage = System.IO.File.OpenRead(AppSettings.tmp_path + _filename);
                  return await Task.FromResult(File(temporaryImage, "image/jpeg"));
        }



I try to access it (returns 404)


      https://example.com/demo/ior/api/default/getfile/AMRFHRNMUIMMSLO.jpeg

Comment: Wait. Are you trying to stream the image or make it viewable in the browser? Also is the controller name defaultController or just default?

Comment: One more thing Could you include this code properly in the question? Please!

Comment: @Donald it has come to my attention that for some reason, you have set the route value as null, please look at the [HttpGet({_filename})] attribute that you have set, that overrides the default mvc route. Remove that and try the following url. [link](https://example.com/demo/ior/api/default/getfile/?_filename=AMRFHRNMUIMMSLO.jpeg)